# Systrace not showing JavasScript stuff after upgrade to React Native 0.27.0

Tags: react-native

I've been using systrace on on IOS (from the rage-shake dev menu) to track down performance issues. It used to show details of which views where taking time but after the upgrade to 0.27.0 my Systrace profiles no longer show any details from within the JavaScript parts. I can't find much documentation or discussion of Systrace so I'm not sure if this is a bug or just a change in how it works.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I experience the same here. I asked about this on Facebook react-native group and they wanted me to check the jsCodeLocation url contains "dev=true". Adding that didn't help for me though.

Comment: That fixed it for me, thanks! If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Amazing, I'm probably having another problem then. I'm adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiling javascript execution is only possible in `DEV` mode currently: check out the [source code.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/require.js#L100)

1. Open AppDelegate.m file in Xcode.
2. Add `dev=true` query to `jsCodeLocation` string.

> jsCodeLocation = [NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];